# jQuery sortable plugin - Get id of target item when hover over it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery sortable plugin to move items from one list to another. While I'm dragging the item it should get first the id of that item and then get id of the item I'm hovering over to in order to replace it if value is the same or move item back to original list if value is different.

I can get id of selected item.

How can get id of the target item when I hover over it?

I've set second list to be disabled because I would like to move items only from the `sortable1` list to `sortable2`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",

    start: function(event, ui) {
      var itemId = ui.item.attr("id"); // Get id of source item
    }
  });

  $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    dropOnEmpty: false
  });

  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").disableSelection();

  $("ul.dropfalse").sortable("disable"); // Disable second list
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
  <li id="test1" class="ui-state-default"><label>Item 1</label></li>
  <li id="test2" class="ui-state-default"><label>Item 2</label></li>
  <li id="test3" class="ui-state-default"><label>Item 3</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
  <li id="test4" class="ui-state-highlight"><label>Item 2</label></li>
  <li id="test5" class="ui-state-highlight"><label>Item 3</label></li>
  <li id="test6" class="ui-state-highlight"><label>Item 4</label></li>
</ul>
```

The closest solution I've got is:

```
$('.ui-state-highlight').mouseover(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: You cant have to Elements with the same ID, what I recommend is using a data attribute, and check if that is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put `enable/disable` with `addClass/removeClass` and than retrive the id with `droppable`

with the method `receive` check if it is valid.

```js
$(function() {
  var $dropfalse = $("ul.dropfalse"),
      itemId,
      isvalid = false;
  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      $dropfalse.removeClass("disabled");
      itemId = ui.item.attr("id"); // Get id of source item
    },
    stop: function(){
      $dropfalse.addClass("disabled");
    }
  });
  $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    cancel:".disabled",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(isvalid);
      if(!isvalid){
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        isvalid = false;
      }
    }
  });
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").disableSelection();
  $dropfalse.addClass("disabled");
  $('#sortable2 .ui-state-highlight').droppable({
    over: function(){
      console.log(itemId, $(this).attr("id"));
      isvalid = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
  <li id="test1" class="ui-state-default"><label>Item 1</label></li>
  <li id="test2" class="ui-state-default"><label>Item 2</label></li>
  <li id="test3" class="ui-state-default"><label>Item 3</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
  <li id="test4" class="ui-state-highlight"><label>Item 2</label></li>
  <li id="test5" class="ui-state-highlight"><label>Item 3</label></li>
  <li id="test6" class="ui-state-highlight"><label>Item 4</label></li>
</ul>
```